# fast blocktime in private net

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, block-interval

I need a long-running private Ethereum net (at least for 2 weeks) with fast block times. I have a single machine which is mining. When setting the difficulty very low, the block-time is very fast in the beginning. "Unfortunately" the difficulty gets adjusted so that after some hours the block-time gets towards the usual 14s. Is there a way to change that? I assume I can re-build geth and set the target block-time somewhere? Or is there any easier method?

Comment: If you're using a private network, do you really want PoW? You might want to loo into a PBFT solution

Comment: correct, but `geth` seems to be the most stable bet on the market right now. desperately trying with eris:db but not really getting far right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to edit the source code for geth to do what you want.

Simply comment out the body of `CalcDifficulty` (line 265 in core/block_validator.go) and replace it with

```
return parentDiff;
```

Then set the difficulty in the genesis block file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as a getting-started project I am building a `fast-geth` version: https://github.com/SCBuergel/go-ethereum Figuring out the build tools (go + gopath and friends....) took a bit longer but now it is already building the DAG :)

Comment: Congrats! Just my opinion, but I think you should keep looking into eris. A blockchain without a strong consensus mechanism is just a bad database

Comment: Agree. But I want some "plan B" and also want an ease "PoC"-ethereum.

Comment: BTW: every now and then I get `We are too far in the future. Waiting for 5s` I assume that is due to the hard-code of the difficulty and cant be avoided?

Comment: That is due to the miner getting ahead of the node, because the difficulty is so low that the miner mines 5 blocks before the node can add them to the chain properly. You can fix it by increasing the difficulty a bit

Comment: I edited to make it easier to change difficulty; now it should just use the difficulty in the genesis block, so you don't need to recompile every time you change it